# How to control buttons order in Samsung Android 13 media notificaitons

Tags: android, notifications, samsung-mobile

Since I started targetting Android 13 my app media notification shows controls in random order only on Samsung devices running Android 13. I know that the media notification behavior changed in Android 13 and that the notification now shows the action enabled on the mediasession. I'm adding custom controls like this

```
                stateBuilder.addCustomAction(new PlaybackStateCompat.CustomAction.Builder(CUSTOM_ACTION_PREVIOUS_EPISODE, PodcastAddictApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.previous), R.drawable.ic_previous_track_dark).build());
                stateBuilder.addCustomAction(new PlaybackStateCompat.CustomAction.Builder(CUSTOM_ACTION_REWIND, PodcastAddictApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.fastRewindTrackButtonContentDescription), R.drawable.ic_rewind_dark).build());
                stateBuilder.addCustomAction(new PlaybackStateCompat.CustomAction.Builder(CUSTOM_ACTION_FASTFORWARD, PodcastAddictApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.fastForwardButtonContentDescription), R.drawable.ic_fast_forward_dark).build());
                stateBuilder.addCustomAction(new PlaybackStateCompat.CustomAction.Builder(CUSTOM_ACTION_NEXT_EPISODE, PodcastAddictApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.next), R.drawable.ic_next_track_dark).build());
```

But Samsung device are ignoring this order and showing the same controls in a random order like fast forward first, followed by previous track, then play/pause button, then rewind and next track. I don't see any logic here. If anyone has any idea on how I can fix this that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using custom actions for what are built in playback controls?

Comment: Yes because user can customize which controls are displayed and depending on this only custom controls allows selecting the order (Except of course on Samsung devices)